# useEffect hook, how to use props, but don't update on them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using a `useEffect` hook to trigger some actions when a component mounts.

Here is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(
      bar1 ? graphData.displayedItems[bar1.value] : null,
      bar2 ? graphData.displayedItems[bar2.value] : null,
      by ? byOptions[by.value] : null
    )
  }, [])
```

This code works fine, but I get a warning:

> Line 54:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'bar1', 'bar2', 'by', 'byOptions', and 'graphData.displayedItems'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I don't want to add them to the dependency array, because that way it will run each time one of those props updated. And I just want to run once when a component mounts.

Is there a way to get rid of the warning, without adding them to the dependency array?

I know this warning can be overwritten by an ESLint configuration. But I don't want that; I want the proper solution. If React has added this warning, must be a solution for this.

I'm learning to use hooks. Is this valid? Should I use a componentDidUpdate on this case?

Comment: What do you mean by *"bust by a solution for this"* (it seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: In this case, using a `//eslint-disable-next-line [rulename]` seems entirely appropriate. The lint rule is to guard against _common_ mistakes, not tell you how to code. The ignore line tells lint "I know I have unlabelled dependencies, this is intentional and expected". I suppose you could hide that way with a `useMountEffect` or similar hook of your own: `useMountEffect = fn => useEffect(fn, []);`

Comment: could you try this way, 
useEffect(() => {
    onChange(
      bar1 ? graphData.displayedItems[bar1.value] : null,
      bar2 ? graphData.displayedItems[bar2.value] : null,
      by ? byOptions[by.value] : null
    )
  }, [bar1 , bar12])

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorry, was `Must` edited

Comment: @AkhilAravind I tried, but then it enters each time that changes